# Eclipse project - wrong svn repository

Tags: eclipse, svn

Whenever I import a project from svn repository, the project's repository in the project explorer points to a wrong repository location. I do not know how to correct this.

A screenshot of how it looks:

[image: Wrong repository]

As you can see the project 'modelengine' points to a repository called 'magicmirror'. Please suggest how this can be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this will fix your problem:
In Eclipse: Right click on modelengine Team > Switch to another Branch/...

Comment: The url that the project corresponds to in the "Switch" dialog is actually pointing to the right location.